# My laptop screen is off even my PC is working

Tags: display, troubleshooting, lenovo-laptop, thinkpad, laptop-repair

I was working on my laptop and then I turned if off to leave home only for 1hr.

When I'm back I turned it on but my screen stays black, even though my power button is green which means it is working. Also my speaker works.

I live alone, nobody touched it, I have a Lenovo ThinkPad. Hopefully someone can help me,
thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: It looks like it's on but with minimal brightness. You can try increasing it. And problems waking up from suspension are often related with the firmware. So, update UEFI.

Comment: 1) If you look at the screen from different angles, can you see a faint image of what should be there? If so, then there could be a display backlight problem. 2) Can you plug an external display into the laptop, in case it has somehow decided to use an external display instead of the built-in one? (An external display includes connecting the laptop to a TV with an HDMI lead.)

Comment: @ChanganAuto when I reboot my laptop I should see the Lenovo welcome message that comes before entering Windows, can't see it either to enter my bios to update it.

Comment: If you "turn it off" by closing the lid then it suspends, it's not the same as shutting down. And you return an open the lid it wakes up from suspension which is quite different from rebooting.

Comment: @AndrewMorton brother your idea of linking my laptop to another screen is good, I can see my kali Linux, but I can't see the Lenovo welcome message and the Dual boot list that gives Me the choice to use Kali or Windows. It goes directly to Linux

Comment: This looks like the backlight for the screen has failed. You should be able to purchase a replacement from ebay to replace it yourself or take it to a repair shop if you aren't confident making that sort of repair.